# How to call a new activity in the OnClickListener () LazyAdapter

Tags: android, image, android-intent, onclicklistener, android-lazyadapter

I want to call a new activity via click on the picture on the lazy adapter, but why in the following line appears Intent error "The constructor Intent(LazyAdapter, Class) is undefined"

```
// Click on Image
     gambar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            String strImageID = data.get(position).get("ImageID").toString();
            String strImageName = data.get(position).get("ImageName").toString();
            String strImagePathFull = data.get(position).get("ImagePathFull").toString();

            Intent newActivity = new Intent(LazyAdapter.this,VoteActivity.class); //Line error
            newActivity.putExtra("ImageID", strImageID);
            newActivity.putExtra("ImageName", strImageName);
            newActivity.putExtra("ImagePathFull", strImagePathFull);
            startActivity(newActivity); //line error
            }
        });
```

What steps am I doing wrong to call new activity in lazyadapter. I plan images on LazyList can be clicked, then appear a new activity with the bigger picture.
Please help, am I wrong to call a new activity. What should I do so that the image can be clicked LazyList then performed with a full-size image and then do the voting.

Answer (score 1):

It should be context of your Activity not the Adapter class,

`Intent newActivity = new Intent(YourActivity.this,VoteActivity.class);`

instead of

`Intent newActivity = new Intent(LazyAdapter.this,VoteActivity.class);`

Comment: I LazyList shown in fragment_2 what is the context is fragment_2? like this:
NewActivity intent = new Intent (Fragment_2.this, VoteActivity.class);
Or is all of the above script should I put in fragment_2 not in LazyAdapter?
I use ABS then when I want to click the image appears a new activity.

Comment: you can use `getActivity()` from your Fragment in place of `context`

Comment: This means that all the above script placed in Fragment_2 not in LazyAdapter?